# ICU Collator Base on Locale and Customize Rule

Tags: mysql, sorting, sqlite, locale, icu

If its possible to use Collator of ICU collation service which is base on both simultaneously :

1. Locale base like "ko_KR"   ( coll = ucol_open("ko_KR", &status) )
2. Customized Rules ie "tailoring" ( coll = ucol_openRules(rlz, rlen, UCOL_OFF,UCOL_TERTIARY,NULL,&status) )

Collator_Final = Collator_Locale  + Collator_customize_rule

If yes, then please suggest how we can use collator base on both at same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a reply on the mailing list to your question [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/icu/mailman/icu-support/thread/AANLkTi%3D26rvW9d29Z0_bUf%3DH_f0zR5_YmdP%2B%3DGm4TMgE%40mail.gmail.com/#msg27262132)

To summarize and expand:

1. You can get the rules needed for a collator from ICU, using [`ucol_getRules()`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/ucol_8h.html#a47699dcfa9c862b4011aea1927c53d4b)
2. You can concatenate those base rules (such as `ko_KR`) with your custom rules.

Comment: Too bad, the linked entry is no longer findable (404) - the answer would have interested me now, 10 years later, too.

Comment: @Wolfgang let me see what I can do.

Comment: That would be great @Steven, thank you in advance!

Comment: @Wolfgang updated link and added explanation here